# User cannot stay logged in in my app Nodejs+Mysql+HBS

Tags: node.js, authentication, handlebars.js

i am following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VavWEtI5T7c

The problem is: when a user is logged in after the authentication, is not keeping him logged, and so he can't access the profile page.
I buyed the complete package and the complete course of this youtuber, but it don't helped at all cause even if the files are IDENTICAL, the session is not working.

The snippet of the login is as following, if you want more, here is my github so you can visualize all the project --> https://github.com/AlessioDeMarino/progetto_pwm

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const { promisify } = require('util');


const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE
});
// ****** LOGIN *******

exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //const { email, password } = req.body;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    
    if (!email || !password) {
      return res.status(400).render('login', {
        message: 'Please provide an email and password'
      })
    }
    
    db.query('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_EMAIL = ?', [email], async (error, results) => {
      console.log(results);

      if (!results || !(password == results[0].USER_PWD)) {
        
        res.status(401).render('login', {
          message: 'Email or Password is incorrect'
        })
      } else {
        const id = results[0].id;
        // qui gli dò il token
        const token = jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
          expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
        });

        console.log("The token is: " + token);
       
        const cookieOptions = {
          expires: new Date(
            Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
          ),
          httpOnly: true
        }

        res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);
        
        res.status(200).redirect("/");
      }

    })

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

The routes are show below :

```
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login');
});

router.get('/profile', authController.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user);
  if (req.user) {
    res.render('profile', {
      user: req.user
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
```

In the index page where user should see the profile tab after logged in:

```
<body>
  <nav>
    <h4>Node MySQL</h4>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      {{#if user }}
      <li><a href="/profile">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="/auth/logout">Logout</a></li>
      {{else}}
      <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
      {{/if}}
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

I realy don' t understand what possibily go wrong, cause i see the cookie and i see the token, why so i am not keeped in?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First can you show routes for getting profile page, it should have middleware for checking cookie and decoding token that it can recognize who has logged in.
Here you are showing only logic for signing token and returning it.
And second you can refactor respond

```
    res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);
    
    res.status(200).redirect("/");
```

to

```
res.status(200).cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions).redirect("/");
```

Comment: Edited with your request, thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You could have been kind upvoting my answer if that helped